# Effective indexing and querying of overlapping date/time ranges

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following schema:

```
AccountId: int
StartDateTime: datetime2(0)
EndDateTime: datetime2(0)
```

I want to be able to query this for rows with a certain `AccountId`, and whose date range *intersects* with a specified date range. E.g:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ... AS d
WHERE d.AccountId = @AccountId
    AND d.StartDateTime <= @EndDateTime
    AND d.EndDateTime >= @StartDateTime
```

This will be a very large table and I'll want to be able to query it as efficiently as possible. I've specified a single composite index of `AccountId`, `StartDateTime`, and `EndDateTime`.

Will this index, and the above query work effectively together? If not, what would be a better alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a good index to me.  Load some data and look at the query plan.

Comment: Check with sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to see if the index is used

Comment: How many rows will you typically have for each AccountId?

Comment: Because you are using `d.EndDateTime >= @StartDateTime` then the second column in the  index should be `EndDateTime`  like this:`CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Table1_AccountID_End_Start] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
 [AccountId] ASC,
 [EndDateTime] ASC,
 [StartDateTime] DESC
)`

Comment: If `AccountId` is the primary key (default sql server will create a clustered index), then for the query you have specified wont even need an additional index (just having 3 columns `accountid,startdateTime,enddatetime`). It will do an Index seek. Also, you should not use `select *`, instead explicitly specify column names.

Comment: You might take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/most-efficient-way-to-retrieve-date-ranges  I think that your problem is similar, except you would always want `accountId` to precede any other index columns (assuming that you will always be querying a single `accountId` out of many accountIds overall)

Answer (score 2):

If the intervals within a particular account do not overlap with each other, you can replace your query with a TOP (1) query, to find the last start date before your desired end date. Do the same but opposite to get your earliest end date after your desired start date. These will form a small range you can use to check.

If they do overlap within a particular account, then you have one of the classically hard problems, and I'd recommend you read the material that Dejan Sarka has written at http://solidqblogs.azurewebsites.net/en/businessanalytics/interval-queries-in-sql-server-part-1/ (and its follow ups).

The problem is that an indexes on either startdate or enddate are less than ideal, because either one alone doesn't give a clue about whether the interval reaches your desired range. Another strategy is useful instead, such as indexing values within the range (lots of storage, and you have to consider the granularity), or come up with a creative solution such as interval trees or spatial analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as previous comments indicate this index looks to be the correct one.

Few notes -

- You may want to consider using a clustered index, assuming those are 
  the typical queries you'll be running on the table
- If the planned results are very large (say, 1m rows for an
  account/date-range) consider applying some additional filtering (for 
  example, top x,paging etc) as even if the query/index are optimal -
  returning huge chunk of data takes its own time & resources.