# Poor temporal table performance on older values

Tags: sql-server, performance, temporal-tables

I'm encountering a strange issue occurring when accessing historical records within a temporal table. Queries that access the older entries in the temporal table via the AS OF sub-clause take longer than queries on recent historical entries.

The historical table was generated by SQL Server (includes a clustered index on the date columns and uses page compression), I have added 50 million rows to the historical table, and my queries were retrieving about 25,000 rows.

I have tried to determine the root cause of the issue but have not been able to identify it. So far I have tested:

- Creating a test table with 50 million rows with a clustered index to see if the slow down was simply due to volume. I was able to retrieve 25K rows at constant time (~400ms).
- Removing page compression from the historical table. That had no effect on the retrieval time but did significantly increase the size of the table.
- I tried accessing the rows of the history table directly using an ID column vs the date columns. This is where things were a bit more interesting. I could access older rows in the table at ~400ms where as with the AS OF sub clause it would take ~1200ms. I tried filtering on my test table on the date column and noticed a similar slowdown when compared to filtering on the ID column. This leads me to believe that the date comparisons are behind some of the slowdown.

I want to look at this more but I also want to make sure that I am not barking up the wrong tree. First, has anyone else experienced this same behavior when accessing older historical data in a temporal table (we only noticed slow downs passed 10 million rows)? Second, what are some strategies I can use to further isolate the root cause of the performance issue (I just started looking into execution plans but it is still a bit cryptic to me)?

#### Execution plans

These are simple retrieval queries: the first accesses older rows, the second accesses newer rows.

[Older Rows](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk-IU-exE) ~1200ms execution time

[Recent Rows](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJzrDZxlV) ~350ms execution time

#### Table details

These are the columns in the temporal table. The history table has the same columns but does not have a primary key (as per the history table requirements): 
[image: Temporal table column]

Below are the indices on the history table:
[image: Indices on the history table]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a comment from [Zane](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10414/zane) on your question, he stated:

> ...It seems like part of your problem is you're reading 50 million rows in order to return 20K in the plan.

This is, indeed, the problem.  There's no index available to push some, or all, of the predicates down to the storage engine.  Microsoft recommends this baseline indexing strategy for temporal tables in the Docs article [Temporal Table Considerations and Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations?view=sql-server-2017):

> An optimal indexing strategy will include a clustered columns store index and / or a B-tree rowstore index on the current table and a clustered columnstore index on the history table for optimal storage size and performance. If you create / use your own history table, we strongly recommend that you create this type of index consisting of period columns starting with the end of period column to speed up temporal querying as well as speeding up the queries that are part of the data consistency check. The default history table has a clustered rowstore index created for you based on the period columns (end, start). At a minimum, a non-clustered rowstore index is recommended

The phrasing of that is a little confusing (to me, anyway).  But the takeaway is that you could create these indexes to improve performance some, if not quite a lot:

#### NC index on the current table, leading with `SysEndTime`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SysEndTime_SysStartTime 
ON dbo.Benefits (SysEndTime, SysStartTime)
/*INCLUDE (ideally, include your other important fields here)*/;
```

This will allow you to avoid reading some of the rows in the current table by seeking to the appropriate end time.

#### CCI on the history table

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ix_BenefitsHistory
ON dbo.BenefitsHistory
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

This will let you get batch mode on the history table, which should make the scans much faster.

#### NC index on the current table, leading with `SysStartTime`:

See Paul's answer to the question [Most Efficient Way to Retrieve Date Ranges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10134/6141) for more details on why indexing for date range queries is hard.  Based on the logic there, it makes sense to add another NC index on the current table that leads with SysStartTime, so that the optimizer can choose which one to use based on statistics and the specific parameters of your query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SysStartTime_SysEndTime
ON dbo.Benefits (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
/*INCLUDE (ideally, include your other important fields here)*/;
```

---

Creating the 3 indexes outlined above made a significant difference in resource usage in my test cases.  I set up a test case which runs two queries that return 1.5 million total rows.  Both the history and current tables have 50 million rows).

*Note: To reduce SSMS overhead, I ran the test with "Discard results after execution" option enabled.*

[Execution Plan - Default Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syj8nsADV)

Logical reads: 1,330,612
CPU time: 00:00:14.718
Elapsed time: 00:00:06.198

[Execution Plan - With Indexes Described Above](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJmPpjAPE)

Logical reads: 27,656 (8,111 row store + 19,545 columnstore)
CPU time: 00:00:01.828
Elapsed time: 00:00:01.150

As you can see, all 3 measures dropped significantly - including total elapsed time, from 6 seconds to 1 second.

---

The other option presented by the Docs article is to forgo the two NC indexes on the current table in favor of a clustered columnstore index.  In my test, performance was very similar to the indexing solution described above.

Answer (score 3):

The `FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF` clause tries to return the dataset as it existed at the stated time. This means that updates have to be rolled back internally, deletes have to be 'undeleted', and inserts have to be ignored, based on the system time of the request.

The farther in the past the AS OF time is, the more work needs to be validated to ensure that the temporal table is as it existed at the specified system time, and thus the longer the query will take.

IF the data table is just a logging table, and no changes are made to the data, then using the date logged and an index will return data faster and more consistently. Whether to use the temporal features in this case is unnecessary. However, if changes are made to the rows (other than inserts), then using the temporal table feature is the only way to return the exact data being requested (the state of the table as it existed at that specific time), and you will just have to accept the additional overhead of the temporal queries.

Note: The "rollbacks" are not actual rollbacks. Temporal tables use two tables - a Current table, and a History table. When a row is changed, a copy of the previous version is inserted into the History table with the time range that the row was valid. If you insert a row at 10/20/2018 10:20:20.18, update a value at 10/25/2018 10:25:20.18, and update it again at 12/01/2018 12:01:20.18, you have the latest version of the row in the Current table with a start date of 12/01/2018 12:01:20.18, and two rows in the history table with valid ranges of 10/20 to 10/25/2018, and 10/25 to 12/01/2018

Comment: Thanks for the response! That definitely makes intuitive sense, but I did not find any mention of that type of behavior in the docs I read (I only went through the basics of the temporal table in MS's docs). Do you know of any documentation that describes the behavior in a bit more detail?